# React component with re usable avatar

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, components

I'm new to React and have hit a roadblock. Basically, I'm trying to create a simple reusable component. I am using MUI and want to create an avatar component to be called anywhere with a different image for when it is called. I want to be able to call in an argument when declaring the  component in various pages. Please help

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import frankieAvatar from '/Users/rodriguezmedia/Desktop/react-counter-app/src/images/oink.png';
import { AvatarGroup } from '@mui/material';

const designerOne = {
    src: frankieAvatar
}

export default function AvatarDesigners() {
    return (
        <Avatar src={designerOne.src}></Avatar>
    );
}
```

Comment: This component is not doing anything. Why do you need a component just to return 1 tag which belongs to MUI? Why don't you use the `<Avatar />` tag wherever you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it simply like below.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import { AvatarGroup } from '@mui/material';


export default function AvatarDesigners({src}) {
    return (
        <Avatar src={src}></Avatar>
    );
}
```

The component that you use it:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import frankieAvatar from '/Users/rodriguezmedia/Desktop/react-counter- 
app/src/images/oink.png';
import AvatarDesigners from './AvatarDesigners'

const designerOne = {
    src: frankieAvatar
}

export default function Profile() {
    return (
        <div>
            <AvatarDesigners src={designerOne.src}></Avatar>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is an error loading the avatar image, the component falls back to an alternative in the following order:
the provided children
the first letter of the alt text
a generic avatar icon

```
<Avatar
  sx={{ bgcolor: deepOrange[500] }}
  alt="Remy Sharp"
  src="/broken-image.jpg"
>
  B
</Avatar>
<Avatar
  sx={{ bgcolor: deepOrange[500] }}
  alt="Remy Sharp"
  src="/broken-image.jpg"
/>
<Avatar src="/broken-image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if image avatars can be created by passing standard img props src or srcSet to the component.

```
<Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
<Avatar alt="Travis Howard" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
<Avatar alt="Cindy Baker" src="/static/images/avatar/3.jpg" />
```